# named parameters in a subquery in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate3

how can I pass a parameter to a subquery in hibernate? I am trying this but I get an exception that :currentDate does not exist as a named parameter in (...[query]...) even though the query clearly shows :currentDate in it

The query looks like

```
createQuery
(
    "from mymodel where someid = :modelId and otherKey not in 
    ( select c.otherKey from someOtherTable c where c.updateDate = :currentDate )"
)
.setLong(":modelId", someLongValue)
.setDate(":currentDate", new Date())
.list()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use colons when you set parameters.

```
q.setDate("currentDate", new Date());
```